# What is the best way to import/export variables in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm developing test automation scripts in Cucumber + Puppeteer + Typescript. I'm facing the problem of importing variables being declared in the main module, something like index.js. First, a few words about what I want to achieve:
I'd like to run my tests by executing `test-runner.ts`, not by `npm run cucumber` because the requirements need to have more control on the flow. Draft of the `test-runner.ts` module looks like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');

export let launchUrl: string;

const optionDefinitions: Array<object> = [
  { name: 'country', alias: 'c' },
  { name: 'environment', alias: 'e' },
  { name: 'headless', alias: 'h' },
];

function initGlobals() {
  const options = commandLineArgs(optionDefinitions);

  if (options.environment === 'integration') {
    launchUrl = 'https://example.url.com';
  }
}

function main() {
  let cucumber: any;
  let cucumberHtmlReporter: any;

  cucumber = exec('./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js', (stdout: any, err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });

  cucumber.on('exit', () => {
    cucumberHtmlReporter = exec('node cucumber-html-reporter.js', (stdout: any, err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
  });
}

initGlobals();
main();
```

So, as you see it mainly parse arguments, run Cucumber and exports a variable. The variable is imported in step definition file. Theoretically, it should work fine but unfortunately, it doesn't. While importing the whole function is executed once again. That means every time when `import { launchUrl } from ../test-runner` is executed, a new Cucumber application is run and some kind of loop happens.

The question is: how should I export the variables to achieve my goal and avoid the situation like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its best practice anyway to store your constants in a seperate config file that you can export your launchUrl from. Your test-runner.ts would than import it and mutate it as needed.

```
export const URL_CONFIG = { launchUrl: '' };
```

then in your test-runner:

```
import { URL_CONFIG } from './config';
URL_CONFIG.launchUrl = 'foo'; //Everywhere in the ap launchUrl is 'foo'
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but the idea is to execute the test automation scripts on a particular developing environment by passing env name in the command line. The solution that you proposed does not allow on it, I guess.

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean. When you would set URL_CONFIG.launchUrl in your initGlobals function it would be set through out the lifecycle of the app and wouldnt force you to run initGlobals() and main() everytime you exported since its in a seperate file, you would just have to ensure you call initGlobals before you passed URL_CONFIG.launchUrl  into the command line args

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you. But it's not possible. I can't change value of the imported object. Am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I know when I import an object, a copy of the object is created and I modify only the copy, not the original object

Comment: When its exported as a const its the same object in memory wherever its imported

Comment: Ok, you're right. The solution works but the problem was different. I was running a child node process and it's obvious that the child process does not have access to the same variable as parent one. Anyway, you helped me. Thank you.